# Replace the sheet name in the formula for all cells in a column using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column (AF) in which the formula is currently set as:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('2017_03 Cash'!D:D,MATCH(G:G,'2017_03 Cash'!A:A,0)),0)
```

I want the `'2017_03 Cash'` part to change based on the name of a specific tab. For example, this is for March (03) then the next month I create a new sheet and is called `"2017_04 Cash"`...etc.

If you look at my code below..you will see

```
Set CashWS = Sheets.Add
CashWS.Name = "2017_0" & MonthVal & " Cash"
```

I want to include in the script something that will change the `'2017_03 Cash'` part of the formula in column AF to the sheet that is `CashWS.Name = "2017_0" & MonthVal & " Cash"`

So all the 3's should essentially be replaced by 4's. and then drag the formula down all the way until the last row of column AF.

```
Sub AddSheets()

Dim PrevSheet As String
Dim CashWS As Worksheet
Dim MonthVal As String
Dim lr As Long

NewSheet = InputBox("Which month is this Commissions statement for?")
PrevSheet = InputBox("What was the previous month?")

Worksheets(PrevSheet).Copy After:=Worksheets("Summary")
ActiveSheet.Name = NewSheet

With Worksheets(NewSheet)
lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AG").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells(5, "AE"), .Cells(lr, "AE")) = .Range(.Cells(5, "AG"), .Cells(lr, "AG")).Value
End With    

Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=EOMONTH(DATE(2017,MONTH(DATEVALUE(MID(CELL(""filename"", RC[-5]), FIND(""]"", CELL(""filename"", RC[-5])) + 1, 255)&""1"")+1),1),0)"
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Range("D3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MONTH(R[-1]C)"
Range("D3").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
MonthVal = ActiveCell.Value


Set CashWS = Sheets.Add
CashWS.Name = "2017_0" & MonthVal & " Cash"

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that `MATCH(G:G, '2017_03 Cash'!A:A, 0)` is correct?

Comment: @Jeeped  Yes, it is =IFERROR(INDEX('2017_03 Cash'!D:D,MATCH(G:G,'2017_03 Cash'!A:A,0)),0)      This formula was already in my worksheet when it was given to me and it pulls in the data into that column.

Comment: @RituMishra My comment wasn't only about that question. As you read there, accepting an answer tips both parties. It can also help other people to find a solution that has resolved the OP's problem. It will also increase the viewers as they see the question has an answer. (not right after posting a while later that you made sure you got the best answer possible). Unless you want to start a bounty. Thanks for keeping the quality of SO as high as possible.

Comment: @Masoud not really sure what you are referring to but I just joined SO very recently and am still getting used to this website. Don't understand the intention of your comments.

Comment: @RituMishra Don't want to push you, but if someone posts an answer and that resolves your problem consider accepting it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to create a string that is reliant on a date. I tend to use Format with a mask that contains escaped characters that would otherwise be interpreted as a number.

```
Dim oldws As String, newws As String, oldmn As Long, newmn As Long

oldmn = 3
newmn = Month(Date)
oldws = Format(oldmn, "\2\0\1\7\_00 \C\a\s\h")    '2017_03 Cash
newws = Format(Date, "yyyy_mm \C\a\s\h")          '2017_06 Cash (today is 16-Jun-2017)

With Worksheets("sheet1")
    With .Columns("AF")
        .Replace What:=oldws, Replacement:=newws, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                 SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Thank you..I am going to try this out and let you know if it works!

Comment: This sent my code on an infinite loop and opened up the file opener/explorer window..not sure why it is doing this

Comment: It did not send your code into an *'infintie loop*"; it went looking for a worksheet named *Sheet1* which you do not have and failed to modify in your transition of the code from my test workbook to your own workbook.